# Error With Image Picker in Swift "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key"

Tags: ios, swift, exception, uiimagepickercontroller

While trying to create an image picker in Swift, where the user presses the button and chooses an image, I came across this error:

```
'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<MemeGenerator.ViewController 0x7ff3805a6f10> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key selectedImage.'
```

My View Controller class is [here](http://paste.ofcode.org/dBuv2YymeF2aS2K64W6cEN)

Any idea what's wrong? I can provide more of the files if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually that message means that you connected an IBOutlet link in IB (Interface Builder) between a control and a defined IBOutlet in your code and then deleted the outlet. At runtime when the system tries to hook up the link it fails.

Look through all the outlets (and IBActions too) in your view controller in IB and look for broken links.